# Intel Pentium 4 HT usb boot freezing

Tags: dual-boot, usb

i'm new in linux system i wanted to install ubuntu on my pentium 4 EM64T capable i did all the in the guide explained used rufus to create bootable image and then boot, but i'm encountring problem the bios mostly freezing at startup and sometimes go fine but doenst show usb and sometimes boot from usb but shows

> Boot error

i tried in bios swithcing from enhanced to legacy not working still, i'm using samsung 8gb drive previously i installed win xp from same usb drive
,i took plugged into another "PC Tablet laptop" it showed menu and was working... also i have 2 hard drive
 1. Seagate 80 GB
 2. Fujistu 80 GB this drive is from old laptop,
 while booting removed native win xp hdd.

graphic : intel chipset

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an USB stick, which can be problematic on old machines. Maybe you can try booting from a Ubuntu dvd, like:

[the desktop dvd for 16.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)

Comment: my dvdrom doesnt work...